# "meet now" button greyed out: "Upgrade your license for this feature"

Tags: microsoft-teams

Article:

"meet now" button greyed out: "Upgrade your license for this feature"

Issue:

The meet now button is greyed out although the user has E3 license so skype is enabled.

When I test this with a colleague an click on his photo in the chat sections I can 1:1 Skype.

This counts for everyone inside the organization.

Have you seen this issue before?
See the images.

problem-1 image is greyed out
In problem-2 I hovered over someone's head and I could meet now.

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16490518/26152945/9510b2b6-3b09-11e7-8afd-53739772c1a5.jpg

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/16490518/26152946/9513da90-3b09-11e7-8ae7-942c7b55b770.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are aware of the issue (it's a bug) and are working on a fix to be deployed in the very near future.

Comment: Could you be more specific, what's in the near future? It's a customer with around the 8000 users. If they all start using Microsoft Teams this option is a must.

Comment: I don't have a specific date yet, but I've asked for one.